# Multiplying Fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What would this simplify to?

I got $\frac{4}{-3x+4}$. I don't think that is right. Would it just be -3x??

I get stuck here. $\frac{x^2-x-12}{x^2-3x-4}\times\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+2x-3}$

Comment: In this case, factoring is useful. We get $\frac{(x-4)(x+3)}{(x-4)(x+1)}\times \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x+3)(x-1)}$. Now you can  finish.  Lots of cancellation!

Answer (score 1):

factoring gives $$\frac{(x-4)(x+3)}{(x-4)(x+1)}\times\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{(x+3)(x-1)}$$ now we can cancel out terms everything cancels to $1$. So in the end, no nasty multiplication was required.

Comment: Are you sure you canceled correctly?